# How to block or prevent any other android application calling my application

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an Android application for security reasons I want to block or prevent any other android application calling or accessing my application.

Do we need to give some permissions in manifest.xml?

If not, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing an Android application for security reasons I want to block or prevent any other android application calling or accessing my application.

You have not bothered to explain what you mean by "calling or accessing [your] application".

Third party applications cannot start your activities, send commands to your services, send broadcasts to your receivers, or access content from your providers, unless those components are exported. Components are exported by default if they are content providers or if they have an `<intent-filter>` element in the manifest. Otherwise, they are not exported by default. There is an `android:exported` attribute in the manifest that you can use to override the default -- this is only needed (or even a good idea) to make a `<provider>` be non-exported. Everything else can and should simply skip the `<intent-filter>` to remain private to your app.

Hence, by definition, "other android application" will be able to start up your main activity, as that has an `<intent-filter>`.